# Assert element not on page

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, frontend, testcafe

I'm writing some authorization/role based front-end end to end tests using testcafe and need to ensure certain menu elements are not showing (negative case assertion) and cannot figure out how to assert that a selector does not match.

I have tried:

```
await t.expect(Selector('.m-menu__linktext').withText('Overview').innerText).notOk()
```

But that fails with:

> Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified
>   selector does not match any node in the DOM tree.

How do I assert that an selector does not match any element on a page?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
await t.expect(Selector('.m-menu__linktext').withText('Overview').exists).notOk();
```